# Is it correct to say that $f(t)$ is bounded and piecewise continuous with discontinuities at $t = \pm 2, \pm 6, ...$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, fourier-series, periodic-functions, piecewise-continuity

I have the function

$$
f(t) = \begin{cases}
-t & \text{when, }-2<t\le0,\\
t & \text{when, }0<t\le2.
\end{cases}
$$

and its periodic extension, $f(t + 4) = f(t)$

If I am not mistaken, we have $\lim\limits_{t \to -2^+} f(t) = 2$

and

$\lim\limits_{t \to -2^-} f(t) = \lim\limits_{t \to 2^-} f(t - 4) = -2$.

So is it correct to say that $f(t)$ is bounded and piecewise continuous with discontinuities at $t = \pm 2, \pm 6,\cdots$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: It certainly is bounded and piecewise continuous, check whether or not it has discontinuities though - perhaps sketch a graph.

Comment: @B.Mehta But don't the limits that I calculated indicate that there are discontinuities at $t = \pm 2, \pm 6, ...$?

Comment: We have that $\lim_{t \to -2^-} f(t) =\lim_{t \to 2^-} f(t) = 2$ so in fact the map is continuous

Comment: @SEWillB You're right. I think I found my error. Thank you for the assistance.